# Home Wireless Network setup (Mesh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, mesh-networking

I'm attempting to change my existing wireless to become one mesh network across the whole property. It spans two buildings, an outdoor space, and a driveway All in fairly decent proximity. I'll attach a quick map of the current setup.

[Map of Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mghac.jpg)

- Red indicates desired connection
- Green Asterisks are Routers/Orbis (would like to make all one network of Orbis)
- Black lines indicate current cables and equipment
- Blue lines are buildings

There are currently two ISPs, and the plan is to remove Spectrum. The desired Service Provider will only allow one IP address. The Red line is the desired connection. There are a few modems and switches that are accessible although I'm not sure they are needed. I would like to switch everything to an Orbi mesh network. The current problem that I'm having, is that when I connect it this way, only a single device (IP address) works. How can I allow multiple devices with this sort of setup? The ideal would be to have a private 2.4 and 5g and a public guest network.

Comment: Are you sure the Orbi connected directly to the ISP is in fact a router (i.e. has a "WAN" port)? Satellite mesh nodes are not routers, they're plain bridges (access points) and they won't perform NAT which is necessary for sharing the single ISP-issued address.

Comment: Ohhh got it. Yeah, the issue was created when using the TP-Link router. If I switch that TP-Link device for an Orbi, and the connect that to another Orbi inside of the house via the Cat5 cable should that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. What devices are _currently_ connected and to what? As far as I've found, an Orbi bundle includes 1 router node + 3 satellite nodes; do you have such a router node and where is it connected?

Comment: Thanks for asking for further info. In the diagram in the original post the first device is currently a TP-Link Router. There are Orbi devices only in the house and not the outbuilding. My expectation was that if I connected the TP Link router in the outbuilding and then sent the connection via cable to the house from the TP Link Router into the House that has the Orbi setup I would have wireless connection in the outbuilding as well as the home. For this to work, can I add an Orbi product in place of the TP-link and send the connection via cable into the home so it all works on one network?

Comment: There is an outbuilding with a TP Link Router. From there the internet goes to the home via cable where there is an Orbi router node and satellite nodes setup.